# vscode debugger display binary full set of bits

Tags: binary, decimal, settings, bit, vscode-debugger

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixkww.png)
I am currently trying to use ,b syntax in watch to see my integers in binary, but it not displaying full set of zeroes. For example i would like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixkww.png) to be 00000001 instead of just 1
How can I force this behaviour from vscode debugger?

I do not know what else to try, google search give nothing about it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.